# Passing sensitive information in custom JSON stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I using Opsworks custom JSON in the stack to define environment variables. These include sensitive database details that I don't want to be there as plain text. Also in case, the stack is deleted, all the variables set will be lost.

Is there a way of defining this in an S3 bucket?

Example of what I have:

```
{
  "database": [
      {
         "name": "db_name",
         "username": "user_name",
         "password": "password"
      }
]
}
```

How can I use an S3 bucket instead of custom JSON that opsworks stack provides?

Comment: Not secure as other approach, but you store the file in s3 and pull the file where needed

Answer (score 0):

chef has a built in mechanism for storing senstive information in encrypted form using [encrypted data bag item](https://docs.chef.io/data_bags.html#encrypt-a-data-bag-item)

data bag item is encrypted using a knife command similar to:

```
$ knife data bag create passwords mysql --secret-file /tmp/my_data_bag_key
```

encryption can be verified with a knife command similar to:

```
$ knife data bag show passwords mysql
```

encrypted data bag item is decrypted with a knife command similar to:

```
$ knife data bag show --secret-file /tmp/my_data_bag_key passwords mysql
```

you can also use it within a recipe similar to:

```
data_bag_item('mysql', 'passwords')
```